# How to merge files contains in different folders using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Got different files in different folders. need to merge them using pyspark.
merging can happen using below code but needs to read the files present in different folders

```
sc.textFile(<path>).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(<path>)
```

example

```
/user/home/m_f012345/part0000, part0001, part0002
/user/home/m_f00120/part0000, part0001, part0002
/user/home/m_f123120/part0000, part0001, part0002
```

after merging files present in each folder

```
/user/home/m_f012345/part0000
/user/home/m_f00120/part0000
/user/home/m_f123120/part0000
```

Note: i might be having folders more than 50 and we are not using any format for folders. these are random folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above scenario is possible with below code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
import os
import time
import shutil
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("FileSystem").setMaster("local")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)
path ="/user/home/"
dummy =path+"test"

v = os.listdir(path)
dir =[]
for i in v:
    dir.append(path+i) 
count=0
for i in dir:
    sc.textFile(i).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(dummy+str(count))
    shutil.move(dummy+str(count)+"/part-00000",i)
    shutil.rmtree(dummy+str(count))
    count+=1
```